# OnAreaEntered(Area2D area) error in Godot

Tags: c#, godot

I have two scenes: Player and Coin. Both of these scenes are inherited from Area2D. Code of these scenes:

Player:

```cs
public void OnAreaEntered(Area2D area)
{
    if (area.IsInGroup("coins"))
    {
        area.Pickup();
    }
}
```

Coin:

```cs
public void Pickup()
{
    QueueFree();
}
```

OnAreaEntered checks if the player has touched an Area2D object, and if he has touched a Coin, on the coin touched by the player, the Pickup() method is launched. But it doesn't work. I can't solve this problem:
[image]

Well, I was able to solve this problem by simply changing the data type "Area2D" to the data type "Coin" in the arguments of the OnAreaEntered method. But there is a problem: the OnAreaEntered method will recieve not only data with the data type "Сoin". What I should do?

I know that the OnAreaEntered method really recieves coin when the player touches it:

```cs
public void OnAreaEntered(Area2D area) {
    GD.Print(area.HasMethod("Pickup")); // TRUE
}
```

Comment: An area cannot be picked up. And an OnAreaEntered event does not pass along a coin. You need to provide the script the instance of the coin from outside or look it up in the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using the Call() method:

```cs
public void OnAreaEntered(Area2D area) {
    if (area.IsInGroup("coins")) {
        area.Call("Pickup");
    }
}
```